# How should I store Child Classes in an enumerable and how to access them correctly?

Tags: vb.net

```
 Public Class UniqueList(Of T As BaseClass)
   Inherits List(Of T)

    Public Overridable Overloads Sub Add(value As T)
        If Not Me.Contains(value) Then MyBase.Add(value)
    End Sub

 Public Function [Get](val As integer) As T
        Return Me.Where(Function(cb) cb.Id = val)(0)
    End Function

 End Class
```

I get en error if I try to use it without casting it first, so I I cast it before trying to get my object :

```
dim mylist as new UniqueList(of Baseclass)
mylist.add(new ChildClass(1))

dim x as ChildClass= (mylist.get(1))
x.RandomMethod() ...
```

so I tried to create a new function in my UniqueList class that would cast it for me :

```
Public Function [GetChildClass](val As integer) As ChildClass
    Return DirectCast(Me.Where(Function(cb) cb.Id = val)(0), ChildClass)
End Function
```

but I always get errors saying value T cannot be converted to ChildClass... is there any way to have this function returns me the correct object ?

edit: I cant change it to a list of ChildClass
...

edit :  declare them however you want ...

```
 Class BaseClass 
   public id as integer
   public sub new(id as integer)
     me.id = id
   end sub
 end class

 Class ChildClass
    inherits BaseClass
    Public sub New(id as integer)
      mybase.new(id)
    end sub

    public sub randomMethod()
     'do nothing
    end sub
 end class
```

Comment: Please add declaration of BaseClass and ParentClass. I am looking to understand the inheritance hierarchy. Your class naming is otherwise confusing, since BaseClass and ParentClass should mean the same thing, they are synonyms in English.

Comment: ok I changed it to child class. is it better this way ?

Comment: There is a problem in the `Add` method of UniqueList; you should not be calling `Me.Add`, since it will cause an infinite loop.  You want to call `MyBase.Add(value)` since you derive from `List(Of T)`

Comment: hoo your right, I just saw that. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this:

```
Public Function [GetParent](val As integer) As ChildClass
  Return DirectCast(Me.OfType(Of ChildClass).
    Where(Function(cb) cb.id = val)(0), ChildClass)
End Function
```

Note - this will fail if no elements of type ChildClass are found, you can prevent it from failing by using `.FirstOrDefault` instead of manually indexing `(0)` into the first element. `FirstOrDefault` will return *Nothing* if no elements were found.

Comment: Public Function [GetParent](val As integer) As ChildClass
    Return DirectCast(Me.Where(Function(cb) cb.Id = val)(0), ChildClass)

End Function

this works for you ?

Comment: @ThierrySavardSaucier: Ah, no, sorry, I tried without it, thought you meant you created it to solve some issue, which I was trying to reproduce. The problem with GetParent is that BaseClass cannot be cast to ChildClass. You cannot cast a parent type to a more specific/child type, only the other way around, this is per basic inheritance principles.

Comment: well, shouldn't it be the other way around, an object cannot me insert in the list if it doesnt inherits from baseclass ... so i'd like to force cast it to ParentClass ...

Comment: @ThierrySavardSaucier: Ok, consider an example, you populate UniqueList only with objects of type BaseClass. In this case GetParent will always fail, because it's trying to cast the first element (which is BaseClass) to ChildClass, and it's not possible.

Comment: yea, that correct for me, I'll create a get function for each type ... baseclass is a "must inherit" anyway ...

Comment: yea, it works, i tested it, my "id" property isnt called ID ... my bad

Comment: @ThierrySavardSaucier: Not a problem, thanks for your cooperation. :)